# aws s3 - s3cmd: "WARNING: MD5 signatures do not match:" - what do?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

When I use s3cmd to pull down files (of not unreasonable size - less than 100 megabytes) I occasionally see this error:
WARNING: MD5 signatures do not match: computed=BLAH, received="NOT-BLAH"

Googling suggests that this may be caused by the way S3 segments files. Others have said to ignore it.

Does anybody know why this happens and what the right thing to do is?

Thank you for your time,
-- Henry

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Looking into this deeper, it seems as though s3cmd is reading the wrong md5 sum from Amazon. It looks as though s3cmd is getting its sum from the ETAG field. Comparing the actual data of the object that was PUT with the object that was GET'ed the contents are identical and this error can be safely ignored.

Comment: I got this message and ran a diff against the original file I uploaded and they match, so definitely some false positives from s3cmd

Comment: This could be corrected by now. The topic was opened 3 years ago.

Comment: Doesn't look like it is. @Kru I just tried it for my file and it didn't match

Comment: s3cmd GitHub issue is indeed still open: https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/issues/520

Comment: I still see it :)

Answer (score 7):

The ETag of a file in S3 will not match the MD5 if the file was uploaded as "Multipart". When a file is marked multipart AWS will hash each part, concatenate the results and then hash that value.

If the file does not actually have multiple parts the result will be a hash of a hash with -1 added to the end. Try disabling multipart in the tool you use to upload files to S3. For s3cmd, the option is --disable-multipart.

Answer (score 3):

ETags with a '-' in them are expected, if the file was uploaded using the S3 Multipart Upload feature (typically used for files >15MB or files read from stdin).  s3cmd 1.5.2 knows this and ignores such ETags.  If your s3cmd is older than 1.5.2, please upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bigger problem is you are using s3cmd sync, because it causes it to re-download previously-synced files. To solve this, add the `--no-check-md5` option, which causes s3cmd to only check file sizes to determine changed files (this is good for my purposes, but probably not for everyone, depending on the application).

Comment: apparently that won't suppress the warning.

Comment: editing site-packages/S3/S3.py and removing the warning does. :)

Answer (score 1):

I saw reports about an hour ago that S3 is currently having exactly this problem, e.g. [this tweet](https://twitter.com/ylastic/status/268884514518999040):

> RT @drags: @ylastic S3 returning incorrect md5s to s3cmd as well. Never seen an md5 with a '-' in it, until AWS. #AWS #S3

Though the [AWS Status Page](http://status.aws.amazon.com/) reports no issue, I expect this is a transient problem. Try again soon :-)